# Why is onCreate called?

Tags: android, oncreate

I know `onCreate` can be called multiple times when configuration changes. Is there any way to find out which configuration change caused the second call?

I have one device that calls `onCreate` twice, and one device (exact same code) that calls it only once.

Comment: `onCreate()` is called when the Activity starts. Possibly, one of your devices creates the Activity twice

Comment: You can [handle the configuration change yourself](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange). This also disables the automatic re-creation. The double create is most likely a rotation change.

Comment: @Dhke, I don't want to handle them, I want to know what is going on.

Comment: @BartFriederichs You can save the configuration in the first create and then call [`diff()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#diff%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) to find out  the differences. That needs a fragment with `setRetainInstance(true)` or some other storage, though.

Comment: @dhke, ah ok. I checked the docs and that seems to be the way yes.

Comment: @BartFriederichs You might be able to get away with dumping the configuration in `onSaveInstanceState()`. Nicely enough, `Configuration` is parcellable.